# Can not connect internet from LAN

Tags: lan

I have the below setups. node1 & node2 are in a LAN. Both use the eth0 NIC to connect to LAN. Both are Debian systems.
Additionally node1 is connected to the internet using wlan0 nic. Expectation is that both node1 & node2 can reach internet.

[image]

With this setup, I am not able to access internet. The kernel IP showed the default rule to the router

Basically I am encountering with two issues.

### issue 1 :

### On Node 1

With this setup, the node1:kernel ip table shows the default rule via eth0. hence connecting to router1/LAN.
I tried ip route del & add new default rule device wlan0. ip table looks good(at least what I expected default rule via wlan0). but still, no internet connection.
Question 1: Is this the right way to delete & add the default rule to change the system behaviour to which dev it should choose to send the packets out. Or some additional config I need.

Now With curiosity, I just flipped the dev. Means the wlan0 nic is connected now to LAN & eth0 is to the router2(external net).
ip table shows default rule to eth0. As this time eth0 connected to router2, I got the internet connection. could ping, browse & all.
Question2: Is eth0 always used for default rule. How can I change to other nic. here wlan0.

### Issue 2:

### On node 2

However this success could not last longer as from node-2, I do not get internet connection from node-2.
It's static configuration, the GW is mentioned as ip addr of node-1.

Question3: Is this correct. OR Do I need to do any SNAT or MASQRADE kind of config on node1 to be able to OR the router-2 should take care of that.. What I am missing here to get the internet connection.

---

### I am adding some clarity to the above scenario. & also clarification to some comments as I am not yet authorized to comment.

Internet access to/from node2(if more systems on LAN also) should via node-1 only.
the LAN router(router-1) is dhcp enaled and all nodes are client to it.
Same with the internet router-2.

So in this case do I need to do any special configuration on node-1.

On node-1, ip route : default via  dev eth0
On node-2, ip route : default via  dev eth0.

another tricky question (but less important, I can live with it by using eth0 to my internet connected router), what I have already asked is : why the default is via eth0 always. How can I force it to use wlan0(in my case) connected GW. My del/add of default is not working.

Comment: It seems you haven't explained how node-2 is supposed to reach the Internet: via node-1 or via the router? How is the router configured? You should add the output of `ip route` for both systems. Does the router provide the WLAN?

Comment: What IPs and masks do you have for wlan0 and eth0?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information I can already say that SNAT or MASQUERADE should not be necessary on both node-1 and node-2. That should be done by the system which is connected to the Internet (probably the router).

But if the traffic from node-2 shall be routed through node-1 then node-1 would have to do SNAT or MASQUERADE for node-2 (in addition to the SNAT / MASQUERADE which the gateway / router does for node-1).

Comment: But node 2 is not connected to router 2 with Internet access, looks like he wants to use node 1 to route node's 2 traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IP forwarding enabled on Node-1? Try:
`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

If that works, make it permanent by adding the line:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
into /etc/sysctl.conf (making sure that if a similar line setting it to 0 is removed or commented out).

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming(your aim is to achieve) that all your internet traffic from LAN, should pass via node-1. You are working only with IP4.
As you have mentioned, node-1 is having the connection to the internet already.

On node 2 : the kernel ip table default rule should have GW as node-1 with dev eth0.

On node 1: 
With the above assumption, the default rule should have GW as "router 2" dev eth0.

Additioanlly the below must be true OR added.
1) IP_FORWARD flag.

```
 ipv4.ip_forward flag must be set to 1. (use sysctl or change the sysctl conf file variable)
 # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward="1"
```

note : will not survive the reboot.

2) Add IP Forward rule in filter table. 
This will forward all the traffic from device eth1 to eth0.

```
# iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

3) MASK the outgoing ip

Qu : If the masking of outgoing ip from node-1 is verymuch required to get the traffic outward of router2 (to internet), then who does that MASQUERADE. Ans : Router-2 does it by default.

Qu : Then why router-2 would not do for node-2 or any other machine in LAN.

Ans : As node-2 & others are not in domain of Router-2. In this case node-1 has to do the MASQUERADING explictly for all other nodes connected in you LAN. hence this step.

```
# iptables -nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# iptables save
```

now you get the internet connection from node 2 or from any other system connected in your LAN.

**NOTE :** However the above would not survive reboot of node-1. I am not covering how to make it persistent.

**Caution :** Not sure if the above will work if the NIC to the router-2 is wlan0, as the AP(router-2) may reject the MASQURADE node-2 packets. As the mac id of eth0@node-1 is not registered on the AP, unlike wlan0. Here we have to explictly change the mac address of eth0 packets to wlan0 address. let me know.